# Is there a best practice on upper/lower case for data types in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I realize not everyone frets over such things, but I prefer to "do in Rome" and therefore have adhered to uppercase SQL and snake_case for table names, field names, variables, etc. in the PostgreSQL environment.

However on data types I haven't quite made out if there is any widely held (semi?) standard.

Looking for guidance, I perused [this source document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)... unfortunately it goes both ways. For example (text/TEXT) see below...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dup(int) RETURNS TABLE(f1 int, f2 text) ...
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_password(uname TEXT, pass TEXT) ...
```

So is it the wild west on this topic? Nobody cares? Or...

Comment: I would argue - it does not matter - as long as you keep it CONsistent.

Comment: The one thing that can hurt you badly is using anything requiring double-quoting for identifiers.  My suggestion on keywords is to go with whatever makes it easiest for you unless your project or employer insists on standards.  Here's a recent blog I read on this topic:  https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2020.html#July_27_2020

Comment: Roger that, @MikeOrganek -- I'm no fan of snake_case but here in Rome I use it assiduously. No objects are named with anything but lower_case_as_so...

Comment: Really does not matter. If you go through here [Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) they are referenced as lower case. Postgres project preference is to fold to lower case(vs SQL standard behavior which is to fold to upper case). But as a practical matter you can declare either way.

Comment: Agreed, @madflow -- like the documentation I cited? LOL...

Comment: Yes, @AdrianKlaver -- it does seem that in the postgres documentation it's lower case more often than upper case.

Comment: That comes from here [Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). "The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case." This is for identifiers, but the principle holds.

Comment: you should definitely avoid [quoted identifiers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: Except for type names that does not apply: ```select '1'::"INTEGER"; ERROR:  type "INTEGER" does not exist    select '1'::"Integer";  ERROR:  type "Integer" does not exist select '1'::"integer";  ERROR:  type "integer" does not exist```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is opinion based, but I'd argue that you should use lower case for type names. My reasoning is to use upper case for keywords and lower case for identifiers, and type names are identifiers.

Comment: That is where I was leaning, but I wanted to run with guidance from an expert. Thanks for the feedback!